# How to use arbitrary font in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, xetex, fontspec

I produce the following chart:

[image]

With the following code (compiled with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % more control over colors
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% fonts
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{[opensans.ttf]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
country, 2Q20, 3Q20
US, 2, -1
Euro Area, 2, -2
UK, 2,-3
PR China, 2,-4
Korea, 2,-5
Chinese Taipei, 2,-6
Singapore, 2,-7
Indonesia, 2,-8
Philippines, 2,-9
Malaysia, 2,-10
}\chart

\begin{axis}[
font = \footnotesize,
width = 10cm,
height = 6cm,
ybar,
bar width=2mm,
axis lines=left,
enlarge x limits=0.1,
enlarge y limits={.1, upper},
%
% y ticks style and label
ymin=-13,
ylabel={year-on-year change (\%)},
ylabel shift = 1pt,
ytick distance = 5,
%
% x axis ticks and style
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\chart}{country}, 
axis x line shift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}},       
xticklabel shift={-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/axis x line shift}},
table/x expr = \coordindex,                   
x tick label style = {rotate=90},]
%
% done with the axis, now the plots
\addplot [black, fill, draw opacity = 0] table [y=2Q20]  {\chart};
\addplot [red, fill, draw opacity = 0, nodes near coords] table [y=3Q20]  {\chart};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I am using `fontspec` to use Open Sans as my typeface (to download the `opensans.ttf` file I use, go to the [Overleaf for this chart](https://www.overleaf.com/read/ycryvskgkztw)).

However, it applies only to the text, and not to the axis labels or nodes.

How can I use the otf/ttf file of my choice and have it apply to all those as well?

Comment: It appears to me that it is using a sans-serif font on the axis,labels, which is where you placed your `font=` command, just not on the numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. The y-axis numbers at still the default LaTeX font, no?

Comment: If I had to bet, the numbers are using maths mode, so you'd have to change the maths font (or somehow tell `pgfplots` to not print ax-tick labels or other numbers as maths).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The axis labels are typeset in math mode and you're not declaring the math font.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % more control over colors
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% fonts
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Open Sans}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Open Sans}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
country, 2Q20, 3Q20
US, 2, -1
Euro Area, 2, -2
UK, 2,-3
PR China, 2,-4
Korea, 2,-5
Chinese Taipei, 2,-6
Singapore, 2,-7
Indonesia, 2,-8
Philippines, 2,-9
Malaysia, 2,-10
}\chart

\begin{axis}[
font = \footnotesize,
width = 10cm,
height = 6cm,
ybar,
bar width=2mm,
axis lines=left,
enlarge x limits=0.1,
enlarge y limits={.1, upper},
%
% y ticks style and label
ymin=-13,
ylabel={year-on-year change (\%)},
ylabel shift = 1pt,
ytick distance = 5,
%
% x axis ticks and style
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\chart}{country}, 
axis x line shift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}},       
xticklabel shift={-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/axis x line shift}},
table/x expr = \coordindex,                   
x tick label style = {rotate=90},]
%
% done with the axis, now the plots
\addplot [black, fill, draw opacity = 0] table [y=2Q20]  {\chart};
\addplot [red, fill, draw opacity = 0, nodes near coords] table [y=3Q20]  {\chart};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]